# How to Push to Account Using ASSUME_ROLE in AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-ecr

What am I missing?  Regardless of what syntax I try, pushing to AWS ECR always lands in the main / management AWS account.  In the AWS console I can switch into that account with the appropriate role.  Using Terraform I can set the `assume_role.role_arn` property to create resources in the correct account.  However, no config or syntax for Docker and the AWS CLI seems to work.  I'm clearly missing a step, property, or global option.

If I go the Terraform route, I can do anything I need.  So, I know it *should* work ...

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-gov-west-1"
  shared_credentials_file = "~/.aws/credentials"
  profile = "govcloud"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws-us-gov:iam::123456789012:role/Build_Administrator"
  }
}
```

However, I would rather NOT use Terraform for such a simple task as pushing to ECR.

I've tried using the `role_arn` property in the `~/.aws/config` and *that* doesn't work...

```
[govcloud]
region = us-gov-west-1
output = json

[govcloud-assume]
region = us-gov-west-1
output = json
role_arn=arn:aws-us-gov:iam::123456789012:role/Build_Administrator
```

In any other scenario, calling `get-login-password` / `create-repository` will leverage the current configured keys and will manipulate the configured account...

```
aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com
aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "complexapi" --image-tag-mutability MUTABLE
```

It feels as if there should be some type of global option to set the target account or `role_arn`, however no combination works...

```
aws ecr get-login-password --profile govcloud-assume --region us-gov-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com
aws ecr create-repository --profile govcloud-assume --region us-gov-west-1 --repository-name "complexapi" --image-tag-mutability MUTABLE
```

**Update 1:**
Feels like I'm getting closer.  After setting the access key I can successfully call `aws sts assume-role` and return a `Credentials` object.  Just don't know what to do with it yet.

**Update 2:**
STS was a waste of time and sent me down the wrong path.  Don't go there.  It's not needed and will pollute your local auth environment for the AWS CLI.

Comment: Sorry what is the issue is here? what is error you are facing?

Comment: I guess you need to generate temporary credentials of assumed role - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-assume-role-cli/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assume a role using the AWS CLI with ECR, you must use the `--profile` property within your scripts and structure the `~/.aws/config` with *two* properties together: `role_arn` and `source_profile`

The `~/.aws/config` requires *both* the main account and the sub-account you wish to work with.  This sub-account contains the role you wish to assume with the ARN is maintained in its `role_arn` property.  The profile of the sub-account is what you will reference in your scripts however the config must also point back to the `source_profile` which will maintain the actual credentials:

```
[default]
region = us-gov-west-1
output = json

[profile gov-mgmt]
region = us-west-1
output = json

[profile gov-staging]
role_arn = arn:aws-us-gov:iam::123456789123:role/BuildBoxRole
source_profile = gov-mgmt
region = us-gov-west-1
```

Your `~/.aws/credentials` file then contains the keys for the main account:

```
[gov-mgmt]
aws_access_key_id = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
aws_secret_access_key = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ab12
```

Once in place, your commands will reference the profile containing the role you wish to assume (the target account) and, where needed, you use that account ID.  In the example of the `get-login-password` command, the AWC CLI is passed the `--profile` property using the name of the sub-account.  Docker will receive the resulting password from the AWS CLI and directly reference the sub-account by number.

For example, here are the commands to create the AWS ECR repository in the sub-account (note both the sub-account ID is used as well as the name of that account's profile):

```
aws ecr get-login-password --profile gov-staging | docker login \
  --username AWS \
  --password-stdin 123456789123.dkr.ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com

aws ecr create-repository \
  --profile gov-staging \
  --repository-name "complexapi" \
  --image-tag-mutability MUTABLE
```

... and the commands needed to push an image into the sub-account's registry with both the `latest` tag and a proper version number:

```
docker tag fredlackey/complexapi:0.0.0 \
  123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/complexapi:0.0.0

docker tag fredlackey/complexapi:0.0.0 \
  123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/complexapi:latest

aws ecr get-login-password \
  --profile gov-staging | docker login \
  --username AWS \
  --password-stdin 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com

docker push 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/complexapi:0.0.0

docker push 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com/complexapi:latest
```